# Using ggplot to make a bar graph showing sums of columns, separated by all column labels, and fill equal to all row labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am wanting to make a bar graph that shows counts of the totals of each column, separated by column name (each bar is for X1, X2,X3....), stacked with a fill by row name (group1:group6). The problem is that I cannot figure out the aesthetic argument in the ggplot call. Here is some sample code

````
set.seed(1)
example_matrix <-matrix(rpois(90,7), nrow=6,ncol=15)
example_df <- data.frame(example_matrix)
rownames(example_df) <-c('group1','group2','group3','group4','group5','group6')
example_df ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you need might like to reshape the data from a wide format to a long format, which is much easier to ggplot with.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

set.seed(1)
example_matrix <-matrix(rpois(90,7), nrow=6,ncol=15)
example_df <- data.frame(example_matrix)
rownames(example_df) <-c('group1','group2','group3','group4','group5','group6')

df <- reshape2::melt(as.matrix(example_df))

ggplot(df, aes(Var2, value, fill = Var1)) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Is there any way to do this with geom_bar instead of geom_col?

Comment: `geom_bar()` and `geom_col()` are the same geom. The only difference is the stat part of the layer. Why would you want to do this with `geom_bar()`?

Comment: Because I'm trying to make a second version of this same graph that works in proportions, not counts, and all of the advice is based on geom_bar. So far none of my applications are working, and I'm wondering if the geom_col call is a consideration

Comment: It somewhat depends on what kind of proportions you're after, but if you want to scale each bar to add up to 1 (100%), you can use `geom_col(..., position = "fill")`.

Comment: I would like the bars to have unequal height, that is, for their height to correspond to the proportion of the total of all of the data points accounted for by that column value. Do you have example code that might show me how to do this?